# Place element at the bottom of div overflow

Tags: css, html, overflow

I'm trying to place an element at the bottom (5px) of a `div` which is inside of another div and has overflow set to auto. So when it's bigger than the parent div, the scroll bar appears.

I also need to place a button at the bottom of the inner div, so it stays at the bottom, therefore I set  `position:relative` to the div and `position:absolute` to the button.

It works fine when the div is not bigger than the outer div, but when it has overflow, the button does not stay at the bottom of it, but rather has a position of 5px from the bottom of the outer div, and when I scroll the overflown div, it scroll with it. It's easier to see here:
[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Zb5DK/1/)

```
    <div class="mainDiv">
        <div class="innerDiv">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            <button class="btn">Edit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="mainDiv">
        <div class="innerDiv">
            <p>Short text.</p>
            <button class="btn">Edit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    .mainDiv {
        border: 1px solid green;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }
    .innerDiv {
        border: 1px solid red;
        background: lightcoral;
        max-height: 200px;
        height:100%;
        overflow: auto;
        position:relative;
    }
    .btn {
        position:absolute;
        bottom: 5px;
    }
}
```

How can I solve this so that the button is always 5 px from the bottom of the inner div when it's overflowing and at the same time 5 px from the bottom of the outer div when the text is short?
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10039660/whatiwant.png
Furthermore, I'm looking for a solution which wouldn't explicitly set the height of the part of the div above buttons about 70% because my buttons might have variable heights (from 20px to 200px). 
Many thanks.

Comment: some code will help other to understand your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add min-height to innerDiv will solve your issue.

Here is a working [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zb5DK/3/)

```
.innerDiv {
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: lightcoral;
    max-height: 200px;
    height:100%;
    overflow: auto;
    min-height:100%;

}
.btn {
   position:absolute;
    bottom:10px;
}
```

Edit: Latest [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zb5DK/9/)

Comment: it's still appearing not at the bottom when text is not scrolled to the bottom : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10039660/fiddle.png

Comment: Do you want the button at the very bottom? or are you talking about text overlapping the button?

Comment: i want it at the very bottom in both cases: when text is not high enough, and when it's overlapping

Comment: that's precisely what i want but is there a way to avoid constant height? because what if my buttons have variable heights

Comment: You can give % value instead of px like min-height:70%;

Comment: it's still kinda constant, because all it means is that the buttons are 30% of the div height which I set to 200px

Comment: I don't think there is another option for you. You can set it to maximum. Latest Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zb5DK/9/

Answer (score 1):

give postion relative to .btn and place the button in parent dive

```
          <style type="text/css">
.mainDiv {
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
.innerDiv {
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: lightcoral;
    max-height: 200px;
    height:100%;
    overflow: auto;
    position:relative;
}
.btn {
    position:relative;
    bottom: 30px;
}</style>
<div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="innerDiv">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

    </div>
     <button class="btn">Edit</button>
</div>
<br>
<div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="innerDiv">
        <p>Short text.</p>
        <button class="btn">Edit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want it to be part of the inner div so it scrolls with it and is at the bottom of it. at the same time I want it to be at the bottom of the main div if the text is not overflowing as in the second div with short text.

Comment: here is your solution .btn {
    display: block;
    margin: -100px 0 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
}

Answer (score 0):

not sure, if that's exactly what you're looking for, but if you don't position the button at all, it stays at the bottom of the inner div.

Comment: yeah but i want it to be at the bottom if the text is short as well

Answer (score 0):

Give min-height to your paragraph element.

```
<p style="min-height: 70%;">Your Text...</p>
```

and change button position from `absolute` to `relative`.

```
.btn {
    position:relative;
    bottom: 5px;
}
```

May this will help in fixed your button position as per your requirement.

**Another Solution**

Add your button inside `<div>` like below :

```
    <div class="btndiv">
        <button>Edit</button>
    </div>
```

Place this div inside your `<div class="innerDiv">..</div>` 
Remove class from button element and give css class to new div.
CSS for new div

```
.btndiv{
    position:relative;
    bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: nice one, it works! thanks! it didn't appear to me, seems quite an easy solution :)

Comment: it's not abstract though, what if I had a button with height much higher than the rest 30%? what if they were variable heights from 20px up to 150px?

Comment: actually it doesn't work because what if I had an <h1> before <p> which I actually do